# Can we create with same deviceid in both IOT Edge and Devices under IOT Hub Device management

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-identity

I have an IOT Hub with name assume "Test-iot-hub"
In this Test-iot-hub(IOT Hub) under Device Management there is IoT Edge and Devices.

I created device id as "test-device-1" under Devices section(Device Management).

Now I want to create edge device with same deviceid as "test-device-1" under IoT Edge(Device Management)

Is it possible to create with same deviceId in both IoT Edge and Devices??

Because i can see aziot-identityd - !!! Hub client error in logs.

Answer (score 0):

Every device that gets created under IoT Hub will get a record under the Identity registry. The Identity registry stores information about the devices and modules permitted to connect to the IoT hub. The device or module ID stored in the identity registry is case-sensitive. This would prevent you from creating different devices with same device Ids.

However, you can create a different device with the same name but with a different case. You can even create two IoT Edge devices or two IoT devices with the same name but with a different casing. Please refer the below image for example

[image]

Refer the documentation on [Understand the identity registry in your IoT hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry) to get more details on the Identity registry and its capabilities.